# Split string based on certain words and remove certain special characters in Python

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a list of tuples with strings. I would like to split up the string into smaller strings based on certain delimiter and remove certain characters.

```
item_list = [('apple OR orange AND NOT pineapple'), ((sugar and salt) or (pepper and vinegar)),..]

# this is how each of the strings inside the tuples look like
str1 = 'apple OR orange AND NOT pineapple'
str2 = '(sugar and salt) or (pepper and vinegar)'
```

Desired results:

```
cleaned_list = [['apple', 'orange', 'pineapple'], ['sugar', 'salt', 'pepper', 'vinegar',..]

# This is how each of the list should look like after splitting
list1 = ['apple', 'orange', 'pineapple']
list2 = ['sugar', 'salt', 'pepper', 'vinegar']
```

This is what I have tried

```
# Delimiter: 'AND', 'and', 'OR', 'or', 'NOT', 'not'
# Characters to remove: '[', ']', '(', ')'

test = item_list.replace('(', '').replace(')', '')).split(' AND ')
```

It gets a bit tricky when there are more than a few delimiter I want to split in the string. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Python Code*

You can use `re.split` with `strip` like (*assuming there can be spaces in middle of word*)

```
>>> item_list = [('apple OR ora nge AND NOT pineapple'), ('(sugar and salt) or (pepper and vinegar)')]
>>> [[x.strip() for x in re.split(r'(?i)(?:\b(?:AND|OR|NOT)\b|[]\[()])', x) if x.strip()] for x in item_list]
[['apple', 'ora nge', 'pineapple'], ['sugar', 'salt', 'pepper', 'vinegar']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str1 = 'apple OR orange AND NOT pineapple'
str2 = '(sugar and salt) or (pepper and vinegar)'
def spliter(line):
    dim = ['AND', 'and', 'OR', 'or', 'NOT', 'not']
    remove = ['[', ']', '(', ')']
    for word in remove:
        line = line.replace(word,"")   
    for word in dim:
        word = " "+word+" "
        line = line.replace(word," ")
    return line.split(" ")

print spliter(str1)
print spliter(str2)
```

**output**

```
messi@messi-Hi-Fi-B85S3:~/Desktop/messi/soc$ python sample.py 
['apple', 'orange', 'pineapple']
['sugar', 'salt', 'pepper', 'vinegar']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to remove the unwanted characters and then [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to get the words. Once you have the words you can use list comprehension to filter out the ones you don't want:

```
>>> str1 = 'apple OR orange AND NOT pineapple'
>>> str2 = '(sugar and salt) or (pepper and vinegar)'
>>> words = {'and', 'or', 'not'}
>>> chars = '()[]'
>>> [x for x in str1.translate(None, chars).split() if x.lower() not in words]
['apple', 'orange', 'pineapple']
>>> [x for x in str2.translate(None, chars).split() if x.lower() not in words]
['sugar', 'salt', 'pepper', 'vinegar']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another take using list comprehensions:

```
item_list = [('apple OR orange AND NOT pineapple'), ('(sugar and salt) or (pepper and vinegar)')]
delimeters = ['OR','AND','NOT','and','or','not']
[[i.replace('(','').replace(')','') for i in x.split() if i not in delimeters] for x in item_list]
```

Gives result:

```
[['apple', 'orange', 'pineapple'], ['sugar', 'salt', 'pepper', 'vinegar']]
```

And pretty simple to follow IMO

Comment: Hey, this is probably entirely inappropriate, but I noticed from your stackoverflow history that you have experience with hosting RESTful webservices on Android using AndroidAsync. I would greatly appreciate if you could help me out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37661766/androidasync-http-server-post-request-with-parameters). Again, excuse this method of communication, as stackoverflow doesn't seem to have a private messaging service.

Comment: Haha, you could at least upvote me ^_^ it's been a long time since I did that stuff so can't comment offhand. But I will try make a sample later and see. One advice I can give is to not use curl, use Postman (chrome app). Just much more control over what is sent and much easier

Comment: Haha, alright, thanks! I did manage to find example code for what I wanted to do [here](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=AndroidAsync-master/AndroidAsync/test/src/com/koushikdutta/async/test/HttpServerTests.java). But please let me know if you have any other information that could be helpful in getting AndroidAsync to run nicely and without error!

Comment: Oh ok, is it working then? Only other help I'd suggest is on the client side use http://square.github.io/retrofit/ because it's amazing

Answer (score 0):

Rather than splitting on stop words, split on spaces and filter out the stop words.  You can remove the punctuation from the individual words with replace.

For example:

```
stoplist = set(('AND', 'OR', 'NOT'))
cleaned = [s.replace('(','').replace(')','') 
           for s in item.split() 
           if s.upper() not in stoplist]
```

output:

```
['apple', 'orange', 'pineapple']
```

The `s.upper` is optional.